# Resize ImageButtons to small icons when scrolled up

Tags: android

I have a `fragment` which has 3 Imagebuttons at the top and a recyclerview at the bottom. I want to pin all the Imagebuttons to the toolbar (after making them small) when the user scrolls tup the recyclerview, so that all the actions remain pinned up for easy access for the user. Please check the attached images to learn more about the problem.[image: This is the top of the Fragment]

[image: This is the middle/end of the fragment, where all the actions are pinned up to Toolbar]

Comment: You can get amount of scrolling in onScroll() and animate the view accordingly.